# Excel error -2147319767 (80028029) Suddenly pops up

Tags: excel, vba

Today suddenly an error popped up in one of our Excel macro sheets that we have been using on a daily basis for three years now. The macro is used to match buy and sell orders based on a forecasted price. On top of this forecasted price we add some uncertainty range to get to the buy_limit and sell_limit variables, which are float numbers. The part of the code that is currently failing, but has worked for three years while nothing changed (not in the code and not in the imported data), is shown below:

```
For i = 2 To 25

    Dim Buy_Limit As Double
    Dim Sell_Limit As Double

    Buy_Limit = Sheets("MAIN SHEET").Range("H" & (24 + i)).Value 'Error pops up here
    Sell_Limit = Sheets("MAIN SHEET").Range("I" & (24 + i)).Value
```

What is happening here? I tried to declare the worksheet before the for loop (as Set mainSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MAIN SHEET")) as some suggested in other questions, but this did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by activating all sheets before accessing them, and replace the direct references (`Sheets("MAIN SHEET")`) with declared sheets (`Set mainsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MAIN SHEET"))` and use `mainsheet.Range("H" & (24 + i)).Value`). The code gets less readable, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using CDbl () function helps.

```
Buy_Limit = CDbl(Sheets("MAIN SHEET").Range("H" & (24 + i)).Value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The error is still showing up after adding the CDbl() function. The strange thing is that I found an older version of the workbook and I compared the code. It is completely the same. When I import the same data again in the older sheet, the code is running fine. Maybe the file is corrupted.